# Sails.js handle errors and chaining policies

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, knex.js

I am using `Sails.js v0.12.0` and I'm trying to modify chain of `policies`, to work with `promises`(In my case `bluebird`).

If error occurs in some of proceeding policy or action, this error should be caught within promise `catch` statement, as result of nested function that returned promise with rejected status.

In case transaction has been completed and response has not been send down to the client this will also bubble up.

In my case I would like to create `policy that creates database transactions` (`isTransational.js` I use MySQL database, with `Knex.js` for that)
and use this `transaction` in proceeding app logic.

To better illustrate the problem and what I already tried:

**isTransactional.js**

Sails.js policy within `/policies` folder:

```js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
   // MAIN ISSUE: There I need to get reference to next middleware 
   // not fn(req, res, function (err) {...) like specified at
   // sails/lib/router/bind.js:179. I tried to get it using 
   // `sails` event `route:route` but it does not fires at the
   // right moment, trying to find other solution.
   var PolicyNext = PolicyHelper.promisify(nextPolicy);

   sails.knex.transaction(function(trx) {
       // If somewhere in proceeding logic will be transaction
       // commited, response to client can be handled inside, 
       // no need to bubble up to this level.
       // If error occurs while performing transaction,
       // first catch block will catch error, if no catch 
       // is present in whole chain, transaction error will be
       // caught at this level.
       PolicyNext(req, res);

     }).then(function() {
       sails.log.info('Transaction has been completed successfully.');
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
       // If we get here, that means some part or transaction
       // has failed.
       sails.log.error(error);
     });
 };
```

**PolicyHelper.promisify**

- function to convert basic `sails.js` middleware function into 
  promise returning function

```js
promisify: function (policy) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var req = policy.req;
    var res = policy.res;
    policy.fn(req, res, function(err) {
      // INVESTIGATE: (this would allow `req.params` aka route
      // params to be changed in policies). Hold on to the current 
      // state of `req.params` after user code was run.
      req._modifiedRouteParams = _.cloneDeep(req.params); 
      if (err) reject(err);
      // Continue onwards
      resolve();
    });
  });
},
```

Any suggestions? **Thank you.**